# Different values when I send a string (with quotes) as a parameter and when I send as a string (take the string from parameter)

Tags: java, double-quotes

I have a variable that contains string.
when I send the variable to the api as param, I get an error.

when I copy the value from variable and send to api, it works well.

I think its related to behavior of the compiler in the context of `\"`.

The api:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/data/v0/query", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    JsonNode mecGraphQLQuery(
            @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String bearerToken,
            @RequestBody String query
    );
```

The api expects to receive the 'query' param in the following format:

```
 "{ \"query\": \"query getMecFeedbackDataByDateRange( $filter: Filter, $numPerPage: Int!, $orderBy: [RecordOrder] ) { feedback( filter: $filter, first: $numPerPage, orderBy: $orderBy ) { nodes { e_bp_digital_uuid_txt: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_bp_digital_uuid_txt\\\") responsedate: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_responsedate\\\") } totalCount pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } }\", \"variables\": { \"filter\": { \"and\": [ { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"gte\": \"2023-08-22 01:52:15\" }, { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"lte\": \"2023-08-24 01:57:15\" } ] }, \"numPerPage\": 1000, \"orderBy\": [ { \"fieldId\": \"e_responsedate\", \"direction\": \"DESC\" } ] }}"
```

I generate the value of a 'query' param from a Velocity file:

```
public String getMecFeedbackDataByDateRangeQuery(String host, String mecAccessToken, String fromDate, String toDate, Set<MecField> fieldNames) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!fieldNames.isEmpty(), "List of fields must not be empty!");
        Map<String,Object> velocityContext = new HashMap<>();
        velocityContext.put("fromDate", fromDate);
        velocityContext.put("toDate", toDate);
        velocityContext.put("fieldNames", fieldNames);
        String query = generateGraphQLQuery(velocityContext, "/graphQLTemplates/feedbackDataByDateRange.vm");
        log.info("MEC GraphQL Query: " + query);
        return query.replace("\n", "");
}


String query = graphQLFeedbackClient.getMecFeedbackDataByDateRangeQuery(mecIntegrationConfiguration.getHostHeader(), mecAccessToken, fromDateAsString, toDateAsString, fieldNames);
```

/graphQLTemplates/feedbackDataByDateRange.vm:

```
"{
    \"query\":
      \"query getMecFeedbackDataByDateRange( $filter: Filter, $numPerPage: Int!, $orderBy: [RecordOrder] ) {
        feedback(
            filter: $filter,
            first: $numPerPage,
            orderBy: $orderBy
        ) {
          nodes {
            #foreach ($field in $fieldNames)
              $field.getField(): fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"$field.getField()\\\")
            #end
            responsedate: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_responsedate\\\")
          }
          totalCount
          pageInfo {
           endCursor
           hasNextPage
          }
        }
      }\",
    \"variables\":
    {
      \"filter\": {
        \"and\": [
          {
            \"fieldIds\": [
              \"e_responsedate\"
            ],
            \"gte\": \"$fromDate\"
          },
          {
            \"fieldIds\": [
              \"e_responsedate\"
            ],
            \"lte\": \"$toDate\"
          }
        ]
      },
    \"numPerPage\": 1000,
      \"orderBy\": [
        {
          \"fieldId\": \"e_responsedate\",
          \"direction\": \"DESC\"
        }
      ]
    }
}"
```

when I send the 'query' variable as param to api - I get error ('invalid input data'):

```
mecApisGraphQLClient.mecGraphQLQuery(MecGraphQLClient.BEARER_PREFIX + mecAccessToken, query)
```

when I copy the data of 'query' variable (right click on the 'query' variable -> copy value) and send as is to the api - it works fine:

```
mecApisGraphQLClient.mecGraphQLQuery(MecGraphQLClient.BEARER_PREFIX + mecAccessToken, "{ \"query\": \"query getMecFeedbackDataByDateRange( $filter: Filter, $numPerPage: Int!, $orderBy: [RecordOrder] ) { feedback( filter: $filter, first: $numPerPage, orderBy: $orderBy ) { nodes { e_bp_digital_uuid_txt: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_bp_digital_uuid_txt\\\") responsedate: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_responsedate\\\") } totalCount pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } }\", \"variables\": { \"filter\": { \"and\": [ { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"gte\": \"2023-08-22 01:52:15\" }, { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"lte\": \"2023-08-24 01:57:15\" } ] }, \"numPerPage\": 1000, \"orderBy\": [ { \"fieldId\": \"e_responsedate\", \"direction\": \"DESC\" } ] }}");
```

I get delta from'DiffUtils.diff':
[image]

**do you know this behavior? how can I send the string as I take it from the variable?**

thanks!

Comment: Those are some rather ugly screen shots, and they can draw attention away from what you are asking. Are you able to include, in the question, body, the important and relevant information *as text*?  Images of text are [not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) here.

Comment: please ignore the screen shots and only read the code snippets I added, I think it's clear enough, please let me know if not

Comment: I can barely tell what’s happening here.  As Old Dog said, the screen shots are very hard to read.  The first screen shot has some code on lines 592 to 603, which we cannot see.  While this appears to have something to do with escape characters, I cannot tell what is a String literal and what is a printed string value.  Please provide us with lines of code, and please explain with text, not images, what the output is and how you obtained that output (such as println statements, debugger windows, etc.).

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer - I updated the post, I hope it's clearer now. thanks!!

Comment: @VGR - I updated the post, I hope it's clearer now. thanks!!

Comment: I am not familiar with Velocity (though I’ve heard of it).  Is there a reason /graphQLTemplates/feedbackDataByDateRange.vm starts and ends with `"`?  That file’s content is not JSON, but rather a string containing a depiction of JSON, which seems unusual to me.  If it were just regular JSON, you could get rid of most of those backslashes, which would make everything easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The api expects to receive the string in the following format (same to value when I copy from variable): ..."*

It looks like the *query* needs to be *"[escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence)"*.
You'll need to add a `\` before every `"`.

You can use the *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))* method to escape the values.

This will preserve the `\"` sequences when copy and pasting the value.

```java
String string = "{ \"query\": \"query getMecFeedbackDataByDateRange( $filter: Filter, $numPerPage: Int!, $orderBy: [RecordOrder] ) { feedback( filter: $filter, first: $numPerPage, orderBy: $orderBy ) { nodes { e_bp_digital_uuid_txt: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_bp_digital_uuid_txt\\\") responsedate: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_responsedate\\\") } totalCount pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } }\", \"variables\": { \"filter\": { \"and\": [ { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"gte\": \"2023-08-22 01:52:15\" }, { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"lte\": \"2023-08-24 01:57:15\" } ] }, \"numPerPage\": 1000, \"orderBy\": [ { \"fieldId\": \"e_responsedate\", \"direction\": \"DESC\" } ] }}";
string = string.replace("\"", "\\\"").replace("\\\\\"", "\\\\\\\"");
```

Output

```
{ \"query\": \"query getMecFeedbackDataByDateRange( $filter: Filter, $numPerPage: Int!, $orderBy: [RecordOrder] ) { feedback( filter: $filter, first: $numPerPage, orderBy: $orderBy ) { nodes { e_bp_digital_uuid_txt: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_bp_digital_uuid_txt\\\") responsedate: fieldValue(fieldId: \\\"e_responsedate\\\") } totalCount pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } }\", \"variables\": { \"filter\": { \"and\": [ { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"gte\": \"2023-08-22 01:52:15\" }, { \"fieldIds\": [ \"e_responsedate\" ], \"lte\": \"2023-08-24 01:57:15\" } ] }, \"numPerPage\": 1000, \"orderBy\": [ { \"fieldId\": \"e_responsedate\", \"direction\": \"DESC\" } ] }}
```

Comment: I tried running the following code but it still doesn't work: mecApisGraphQLClient.mecGraphQLQuery(MecGraphQLClient.BEARER_PREFIX + mecAccessToken, query.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\""));

Comment: @aaa, interesting.  And, it's working correctly if you copy and paste the value?  Can you add that value to your post?

Comment: Escaping typically applies to more than just double quotes. I'd guess this probably needs full JSON string escaping or similar. Your proposed solution is missing at least backslashes, which do appear in the string currently.

Comment: thanks @Luatic. do you have another solution?

Comment: @aaa I don't, since I don't know which API you're working with and what exactly it expects and don't want to tap in the dark. You could try using the JSON encoded string and JSON encoding it again though.

Comment: @aaa, I've revised my answer, it might work now.  Originally it wasn't escaping the _query_ value correctly, which has 3 slashes.